# On the equivalence of the squares of prime numbers p and q in modular pq-1.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Find all prime numbers (p,q) such that $p\not=q$ and $p^2≡q^2$ (mod $pq-1$).

Edit 1:

So what I got so far is that, if p=2 and q=2k+1, then $4≡4k^2+4k+1≡4k^2$ (mod $4k+1$). Adding 16k to both sides, we get $15k≡0$ (mod $4k+1$). Adding k+4 to both sides gives us $0≡k+4$ (mod $4k+1$). Since k+4<4k+1 for all k>1, k=1, so q=3. This gives the solutions (2,3) and (3,2).

Now we can assume p and q are odd, and get $p^2-q^2≡(p+q)(p-q)≡(p+q)(p-1)(q+1)≡0$. Plugging in $p=2k+1$ and $q=2j-1$ yields $(2k+2j)(2k)(2j)≡0$ (mod $4kj-2k+2j-2$). Dividing by 2 we get $(k+j)(2k)(2j)≡0$ (mod $2kj-k+j-1$). Now we get $(k+j)(4kj)≡(k+j)(2k-2j+2)=2k^2+2k-2j^2+2j≡0$ (mod $2kj-k+j-1$). From here I get kind of stuck lol. I think this equivalence does have infinite solutions...

Edit 2: Actually if p and q are 1 and 3 in mod 4, plugging in shows that pq-1=2, which has no solutions. Therefore p and q are both the same in modular 4. Not sure how this helps though.

Comment: What have you tried?   Have you found any pairs $(p,q)$ that work?

Comment: Here's one example: $p=3,q=2.$

Comment: Please edit to show your efforts and to supply some context.  Have you got any reason to imagine that this list is finite?  I note that, say, $(31, 191)$ works...found through a random search.

Comment: Are you in the middle of a book/class involving Number Theory?  If so, what topics are you currently studying or have recently studied in this book/class, that you think **might** be relevant?

Comment: @user2661923 No lol I just came up with this problem by myself while messing around with prime numbers and modular arithmetic.

Comment: +1 to your query, extremely nice analysis.  Hopefully, since I upvoted the query, this may influence mathSE-Number-Theory-Pros (which I am not) to weigh in.